# FFT : not the same boundaries as the example

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft

I have to remake the FFT of an example for a training and I am stuck on a problem : I successfully have the same shape when I plot its FFT, but the boundaries are different from the example.

Here is the function I have to plot and make an FFT of:
[image: formula]

**The function is expected to have a cut-off frequency of 2 Hz (0.5 seconds).**
**(In case you didn't understand : It means that at 0.5 second (and 2 Hz for FFT), the function is equal to 0)**

On the left is the function plotted related to time, on the right, it's Fourier transform.
This is the example. **The plain red line, it is the function I am working on it**:

[image: plot of the example]

This is what i get:

[image: plot of my work]

As you can see, the boundaries of my FFT plot are very different from the example. **I have a factor of 10² in the plot**.

Do you think the problem come from the way I use the FFT ?
It is said that the function is normalized, do you think the difference  comes from this ?

This is the code I wrote:

```
npas      = 32768                                # steps for discretization
t         = np.linspace(0,200,npas)              # time discretized (array of npas elements, from 0 to 200)     
f         = np.fft.fftfreq(t.size, d=1.0/npas)   # frequency (for Fourier Transform)  d = sample spacing (inverse of the sampling rate)
swh       = np.zeros(npas)                       # initialization of the array swh (the function we use)
tau0      = 1.0/20

# creation of the function and it's Fourier transform
swh      = (1/tau0)*np.exp(-t/tau0)*(1 + t/tau0 + (t**2)/(2*tau0**2) + (t**3)/(3*tau0**3) - 0.490*t**4/tau0**4) - np.exp(-t/tau0)*(1/tau0 + t/tau0**2 + t**2/tau0**3 - 0.490*(4*t**3)/tau0**4)
swh_f    = np.fft.fft(swh)                       # Fourier transform of swh

##### Plot #####

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.title("Time Function")
plt.plot(t, swh, 'r'  ,  linewidth=1, label = "SWH B = 0.490")             # plot of swh, function of t
plt.legend(loc = 1, prop={'size': 7})                                      # legend position
plt.xlim(0,1.5)

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.title("Frequency Function")
plt.plot(f[0:f.size//2], abs(swh_f[0:npas//2]), 'r'  ,  linewidth=1)       # plot of the Fourier transform, function of f (frequency)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

Thank you for your attention !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the option 'norm' in your FFT :

```
swh_f = np.fft.fft(swh, norm = "ortho")
```

You can find more informations about NumPy's implementation of FFT here : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got this error message:
fft() got an unexpected keyword argument 'norm'

Comment: Does that come from my importations ? I import the functions fft like this :  
from scipy.fftpack import fft  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np

Comment: You may have an outdated version of NumPy. You can get the same result by dividing swh_f by np.sum(swh).

Comment: Thank you, it solved half of the problem. I have the wrong abscissa, but the right ordinate.

Comment: To solve the other half of the problem, I did : f /= 10e2. However, I don't know if this is the right way to do it.I have now almost the same curve.

Comment: You got the sampling rate wrong. Your signal is defined by 'npas' points for 200 seconds. The sampling rate is therefore 'npas/200'. Simply change the frequency axis to :

f = np.fft.fftfreq(t.size, d=200/npas)